# Checking file permissions across several network shares?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dos

We have several Windows network shares, in a common location (\\server-name\share) that hosts a common set of files. These shares are replicated across roughly 300 hundred servers. We have the actual replication down, but we're running into an unanticipated problem: server admins half the world away changing file permissions on our share, and breaking replication in creative ways.

To detect this early on, we'd like to write a script to check each server's network share and ensure that a few permissions exist for the share folder & its contents:

- Everyone needs read access
- User X needs change/modify
- User Y needs full control

Now, so far I've got a nice script that checks that at least each share exists. The complication stems from the fact that (due to a nice Active Directory tree), the usernames are consistent across servers (always of the form "DOMAIN/user"), but their guid numbers vary.

So far I've been looking at [cacls.exe](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cacls) and the newer version Icacls.exe, but the options are confusing and seem to be centered around changing the Access Control Lists, which I don't want to do. Any tool that's Windows built-in is preferable, I'm just unsure how to approach this.

So it comes down to is: on some arbitrary server, if I only know the NAME of a user, is there a way to figure out what file permissions they have on a given folder?

Comment: You might want to move this question to serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

`icacls` **does** allow the use of the "friendly name" form for specifying the user. Which means you should be able to use the human style names. So 'bob' should point to the same person in all of your domains.

You can grant a user a permission without changing anything else using `/grant:r` which means "if it's already there do nothing, otherwise add it". So,

*Everyone needs read access*
`icacls \a\directory\somewhere /t /grant:r Everybody:(rd)`

I assume you want them to be able to list the contents of the directory as well as read.

*User X needs change/modify*
`icacls \a\directory\somewhere /t /grant:r bobX:m`

And so on. I assume that 'm' is sufficient to convey the 'modify' permission.

ACLs are just another name for "permissions". So, if you want to change permissions then you want to change the ACLs.